# Creation of an Objects

Tags: objective-c, object, allocation

```
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] init];
```

creates a new `Car` object with the name `myCar`. But if it is:

```
Car *myCar = [[DifferentCar alloc] init];
```

What will be created? I know that `[[Xx alloc] init];` is for creating a new object, but what **Xx** does there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> creates a new `Car` object with the name `myCar`

That's not quite right. It should be "creates a new `Car` object, and assigns it to a variable called `myCar`".

> But if it is: `Car *myCar = [[DifferentCar alloc] init];` What will be created?

I am assuming that `DifferentCar` is a subclass of `Car`. An instance of `DifferentCar` will be created, and assigned to a variable called `myCar`. The static type of that variable would be `Car`, but its runtime type would be `DifferentCar` (or one of its subclasses, if the implementation chooses to make a replacement).

> what `Xx` does there?

In the call above `Xx` determines the type of object to which the `alloc` message is going to be sent, ultimately deciding the type of the object being created. Note that since you are calling `init` right away, the object returned from the call may differ from the object being sent into the call.

Comment: Solid answer. Just to be clear, though, the type of `myCar` is `Car *`, not `Car`.

Comment: @Caleb Well, since that asterisk is more of a "syntactic necessity" of Objective-C (i.e. the language makes it impossible to refer to objects through variables without asterisks), I kept it out of describing the type of the variable.

Comment: I wouldn't usually quibble with that -- it's a convenient shorthand so long as everybody knows what you mean. Beginners aren't always clear about the difference between an object and a pointer, though, so I think it's best to be explicit in cases like this one. I didn't mean to correct you, exactly, just to clarify for the OP.